# How to install tomcat on aws ec2 instance with ubuntu

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, installation

I've install Tomcat 6 on an AWS EC2 instance with Ubuntu. I've followed these steps:

1. `sudo apt-get install tomcat6 tomcat6-admin`
2. `sudo /etc/init.d/tomcat6 restart`
3. `sudo gedit /etc/tomcat6/tomcat-users.xml`
4. `sudo /etc/init.d/tomcat6 restart`

   but when I put the public DNS of my instance in the navigator  (http://public-dns-name:8080/), it doesn't find anything.

Comment: Do you have your security group associated with that instance open for port 8080?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd forgotten to install jdk 1.6 before

Answer (score 4):

**Update**

Considering all your non successful tests, you might want to verify that Tomcat is actually listening on port 8080 as expected - please execute `netstat -ln | grep 8080`, which should yield approximately the following output:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

While Tomcat failing to bind to port 8080 should result in a respective error message in the logs in principle, I've encountered a case already, where it apparently didn't, see cherouvim's comment on my answer to [ehcache auto-discovery (via multicast) between 2 instances on the same host](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1322845). The problem discussed there might exist on your system as well, insofar many Java application servers and similar services bind to port 8080 by default - have you installed anything out of the ordinary on your system eventually, e.g. some custom software installed without the Ubuntu package manager?

Good luck!

---

> when I put the public DNS os my instance in the navigator
>   (http://ec2-176-34-239-3.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:**8080**/), it
>   doesn't find anything

Please note the emphasized part of the Tomcat URL you are trying to access: Most likely you have not adjusted your *EC2 security groups* (which kind of resembles the 'firewall' on EC2) to allow inbound traffic on TCP port **8080** (which is the default port Tomcat and many other Java application servers are binding to).

Consequently you need to enable access port 8080 for yourself at least, as e.g. explained in [Adding Rules to the Default Security Group](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/adding-security-group-rules.html) regarding ports 80 and 22 (simply replace these with 8080).

I probably don't have to stress this, but a thorough understanding of the security architecture of the (EC2) hosting environment an application is deployed to is very important for running public internet services of any kind - here are some resources:

- Please at least review the [Using Security Groups](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html) in the official [Amazon EC2 documentation](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Welcome.html).
- For a more concise overview you  might want to read [Understanding Amazon EC2 Security Groups and Firewalls](http://cloud-computing.learningtree.com/2010/09/24/understanding-amazon-ec2-security-groups-and-firewalls/).
- In addition, [Security Groups - Most Underappreciated Feature of Amazon EC2](http://www.somic.org/2009/09/21/security-groups-most-underappreciated-feature-of-amazon-ec2/) is a highly recommended read with more details regarding resulting security architecture considerations.

Comment: I've 8080 port opened, in fact, i have 22 (SSH), 80 (HTTP), 443 (HTTPS), 3306 (MYSQL), 3389 (RDP), 8080 (HTTP*) and 8081

Comment: @Migua - okay, that's very strange then indeed, here's what I'd try next: SSH into the instance and try to access Tomcat via the internal/private IP address, e.g. with [Lynx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynx_%28web_browser%29) (should be available on Ubuntu); of course checking the Tomcat logs for errors might provide more clues as well.

Comment: I've tried to conect with lynx to the private ip, but the message is " unable to connect to remote host", if I make the same with another instances that I have with apache (not tomcat) it works. I'm desperate :(

Comment: @Migua - well, I'm desperately waiting for info regarding the Tomcat logs ;) Any clues there?

Comment: @Migua - see my update for an alternate approach, but please check the logs regardless!

Comment: I tried to acces Tomcat via the private IP, and I couldn't, then I realized that I haven't installed  jdk1.6 , so, I installed it, but it didn't work, then i uninstalled everyting, I started again, and it worked perfectly. Now I have my aws EC2 instance with, apache, tomcat6, mysql and phpmyadmin. Thank you very much! And sorry for the later response, but I'm in Spain and it's for the time difference.