# Spring+Hibernate(with 2nd level cache enabled) in Tomcat(clustered), do I need JTA?

Tags: spring, hibernate, caching, jta

As the title says, I have a web application which should be able to run on cluster with hibernate 2nd level cache enabled and `org.springframework.orm.hibernate.HibernateTransactionManager` as a transaction manager. The application has only one database.  It will be deployed in Tomcat 7, and for some reason the company will not use any application server(I'm not in charge). Now I checked some Cache providers, for example Infinispan, which as the doc says, is cluster safe when JTA is used as a transaction manager.

My job is to research a caching solution which is cluster-safe.
Now I want to know if it's possible to achieve a cluster safe cache with the above stack? Is JTA a must?

Answer (score 2):

I've had success using `org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider` with `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager` in a clustered environment on both Tomcat and JBoss (albeit an earlier version of Tomcat than the version you're using). It wasn't necessary to use JTA.

EHCache supports clustering right out of the box through various [replication mechanisms](http://ehcache.org/documentation/replication/index). I've used the [RMI Replicated Caching](http://ehcache.org/documentation/replication/rmi-replicated-caching) mechanism which uses multicast for automatic peer discovery and that worked quite nicely in a multi-node cluster with multiple caches per node.

Once configured, replication would take place between the caches within a node and between caches across nodes. It was very reliable, transparent as far as the application was concerned and I don't recall ever having to deal with any issues associated with it. It just worked.

You can specify EhCacheProvider in your Hibernate configuration along with the properties to enable second level caching:

```
hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true
hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=true
hibernate.cache.provider_class=org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider
```

The remainder of the configuration is in the `ehcache.xml` file which defines the caches and the replication configuration. It may be worth checking out the [EHCache documentation](http://ehcache.org/documentation/2.5/get-started/index) if you're not familiar with the format of `ehcache.xml` - but they provide a useful example file [here](http://ehcache.org/ehcache.xml).

An example replicated cache from `ehcache.xml` may look something like this:

```
<cache name="example" 
        maxElementsInMemory="1000"
        eternal="false" 
        overflowToDisk="false" 
        timeToIdleSeconds="0"
        timeToLiveSeconds="600">
        <cacheEventListenerFactory 
            class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheReplicatorFactory"/>
        <bootstrapCacheLoaderFactory
            class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIBootstrapCacheLoaderFactory"
            properties="bootstrapAsynchronously=true, maximumChunkSizeBytes=5000000"/>
</cache>
```

And then you'll need to add the replication settings which may look like this:

```
<cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory
        class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerProviderFactory"
        properties="peerDiscovery=automatic, multicastGroupAddress=230.0.0.2,
                    multicastGroupPort=4455, timeToLive=1" />

<cacheManagerPeerListenerFactory
        class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerListenerFactory"
        properties="hostName=localhost, port=40001, socketTimeoutMillis=2000" />
```

That's really about it. There are other ways to configure replication in EHCache as described in the documentation but the RMI method described above is relatively simple and has worked well for me. If you do decide to go with EHCache, in addition to the documentation there are [various posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884760/setting-up-ehcache-replication-what-multicast-settings-do-i-need) on StackOverflow relating to replication that you might want to consult.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
Isn't EHCache not cluster safe? See this http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-cache
Probably this is old but I'm not sure. Doesn't EHCache need Terracota Servers to achieve cluster safety?

Comment: @braincell - I think in EHCache 1.7 Terracotta was needed to enforce Hibernate locking - as that version didn't implement Hibernate's lock and unlock methods - and so it wasn't considered to be 'cluster-safe'. My understanding is that from version 2.0 onwards, EHCache is cluster-safe. See the [EHCache Hibernate User Guide](http://ehcache.org/documentation/2.4/user-guide/hibernate) which says **We expect Ehcache 2.0 to be marked as cluster safe in new versions of the Hibernate documentation**

Comment: Yes but just before that sentence they're saying **In Ehcache 2.0 when using Terracotta, the lock and unlock methods tie-in to the underlying clustered cache locks. We expect Ehcache 2.0 to be marked as cluster safe in new versions of the Hibernate documentation.** 
Still wondering...:(

Comment: Hey, thank you for this reply. I need some assistance on one thing here. I am getting a warning on server startup: `Jun 09, 2014 1:18:14 PM org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionManagerLookupFactory getTransactionManagerLookup
INFO: No TransactionManagerLookup configured (in JTA environment, use of read-write or transactional second-level cache is not recommended` how do I resolve this for caching?